# Weierstrass points and Osculating Hyperplanes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be an irreducible non-singular curve of genus $g$, embedded in $\mathbb{P}^n$ via the canonical embedding.

Let $j$ be an integer, and $P\in X$ a point on the curve. I would like to prove the following statement:

> The integer $j+1$ is a Weierstrass gap for $P$ **if and only if** there
>   exists a hyperplane $H\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{n}$ such that $H$ intersects $X$
>   at $P$ with multiplicity exactly $j$.

Recall that an integer $s$ is called a *Weierstrass gap* for a point $P\in X$ if there does **not** exist any meromorphic function $f$ on $X$ such that $f$ is regular outside of $P$, and has pole of order $s$ at $P$.

This should apparently follow from Riemann-Roch Theorem. Which line bundles should I apply the Riemann-Roch theorem on? This seems to be an important characterization of Weierstrass points, so it might be helpful to have a canonical answer in this website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $s=j+1$.  A meromorphic function with a pole of order $s$ at $P$ which is regular at all other points is exactly a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(sP)$ which is not a section of $\mathcal{O}_X((s-1)P)$.  So $s$ is a Weierstrass gap at $P$ iff $$\ell(sP)=\ell((s-1)P).$$  By Riemann-Roch, this is equivalent to $$\ell(K-sP)=\ell(K-(s-1)P)-1$$ where $K$ is the canonical divisor.  That is, $s$ is a Weierstrass gap at $P$ iff there is a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(K-(s-1)P)$ which is not a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(K-sP)$.  This condition is equivalent to the existence of a divisor $D$ linearly equivalent to $K$ such that $D-(s-1)P$ is effective but $D-sP$ is not effective.  But this just means $D$ is effective and $s-1$ is the coefficient of $P$ in $D$.  The effective divisors which are linearly equivalent to $K$ are exactly the hyperplane sections of $X$ for its canonical embedding.  So our condition is equivalent to the existence of a hyperplane section of the canonical embedding that contains $P$ with multiplicity $s-1=j$, as desired.

Comment: There is no such object; that's not how the proof works.  The proof instead uses dimension-counting and Riemann-Roch.  What step of the proof do you not understand?

Comment: When $X$ is embedded in $\mathbb{P}^n$, a hyperplane section of $X$ is just the intersection of a hyperplane $H\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ (in this case, counted with multiplicity to give a divisor on $X$).  Concretely, in this case, since $X$ is embedded via the canonical embedding, the equation of a hyperplane is a holomorphic differential on $X$ and the hyperplane section is then its divisor of zeroes.

Comment: $h$ is not a meromorphic function on $X$; $h$ is a differential on $X$.  The equation of a hyperplane is not actually a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{P}^n$; it is instead a section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$.

Comment: Thanks I have the clues I needed (please don't delete them), sorry for bothering.

Comment: Thank you so much for writing a detailed answer! It is quite clear. (By the way, I have learnt a lot from your many answers here in MSE. Thanks for those too!)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about the problem (which is essentialy what Eric Wofsey did) is to use the geometric Riemann-Roch. Being a gap means $dim|(j+1)p|=dim|jp|$ and by the geometric version of Riemann-Roch we have $\overline{\phi_K(jp)}=\overline{\phi_K((j+1)p)}-1$ , where $\overline{\phi_K(D)}$ is the intersection of all hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ containing my divisor D. So in our case $\overline{\phi_K(jp)}$ is the set of all hyperplanes passing through p with multiplicity at least j and $\overline{\phi_K((j+1)p)}$ is the set of all hyperplanes passing through p with multiplicity at least $j+1$, hence our condition $\overline{\phi_K(jp)}=\overline{\phi_K((j+1)p)}-1$ implies that there must exists an hyperplane passing through p with multiplicity exactly j.